# jw player video not working if source is content type video

Tags: php, jquery, jwplayer

I am using this code in jw player to play video.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('player_1234').setup({
   file: 'http://localhost/media.php?media_id=1822',
   width: '100%',
   plugins: {},
   aspectratio: '16:9',
  fallback: 'false',
   primary: jwplayer.utils.isChrome() ? "html5" : "html5"
   });
</script>
```

Here, `media.php` file returns the the proper content-type video header() using `readfile()`.

Media.php works fine when i directly enter in browser.

But jw player gives this error message "Error loading player:
No playable sources found" when page is loaded. Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

For the id use this way

```
'id': 'playerID',
```

**Add the following:**

```
'type': 'mp4',
```

Now, the php file should work as the `player's "file" variable`, It will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

To Use jwplayer you have to give the path to video file to get it working.

```
file: 'path_to_your_video_file.mp4',
```